# Windows, bash and `&` sign to run parallel processes

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, npm

I'm using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) scripts for task automation in my node.js app. For example in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "nodemon": "nodemon -w ./src bin/runServer -e js,jsx,json",
  "start-wds": "node bin/runWebpackDevServer",
  "start-dev": "npm run start-wds & npm run nodemon",
  ...
}
```

On Mac OS X command `npm run start-dev` works perfectly - it starts 2 separate processes in parallel. **But on Windows it starts only the first one `npm run start-wds`.** Is there a way to workaround this? Maybe some bash version for Windows? Thanks!

Comment: you can use [`start <cmd>`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) but it open's a new cmd window.

Comment: did you try `npm-run-all` ? Should work on windows too

Comment: @marco `run all` won't be acceptable as there a lot of scripts inside package.json