# how to run 2 watch tasks in VS code?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to run 2 npm scripts in parallel, but this VS Code only runs the first task and stops there. How can I solve it?
My `tasks.json` is as below:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "npm",
"isShellCommand": true,
"suppressTaskName": true,
"args": [
    "run"
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "args": [
            "gulp"
        ],
        "taskName": "gulp",
        "isBuildCommand": true 
    },
    {
        "args": [
            "babel"
        ],
        "taskName": "babel",
        "isBuildCommand": true
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the [NPM package "concurrently"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) may help you.

In the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "gulpbabel": "concurrently \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run babel\""
},
```

Then in `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "gulpbabel",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": [
                "create_one_for_gulp",
                "create_another_for_babel",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally (but not required), you also need to create two [problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks): one for the `gulp` task and one for `babel`. They should be able to extract error details from the merged output and to detect when the respective task's watcher fires/stops (so that VS Code can display the rotating '\' in the status bar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do both tasks at once.  Instead you can do this from npm.

In the tasks.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "npm",
"isShellCommand": true,
"suppressTaskName": true,
"args": [
    "run"
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "args": [
            "gulpbabel"
        ],
        "taskName": "gulpbabel",
        "isBuildCommand": true 
    }
]
}
```

In the package.json file if you are on windows:

```
{
  "name": "stacktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "gulpbabel": "gulp & babel"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In the package.json file if you are on unix/linux/mac:

```
{
  "name": "stacktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "gulpbabel": "gulp && babel"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Is it right in windows? got the erorr as below:
    
> babel ; gulp

▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
; doesn't exist. gulp doesn't exist
▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Fixed above.

Comment: still can't, maybe the '&' symbol not work in windows, ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387347/windows-bash-and-sign-to-run-parallel-processes